# Removing duplicate sets of items in a sequence

Tags: python, list, algorithm, numpy

I have a list, for example `data = [0, 4, 4, 2, 5, 8, 5, 8, 7, 1, 5, 6, 1, 5, 6]`, and I need to remove sets of items from it (max. lenght of set `k = 3`), but only when the sets follow each other. `data` includes three such cases: `[4, 4]`, `[5, 8, 5, 8]`, and `[1, 5, 6, 1, 5, 6]`, so the cleaned up list should look like `[0, 4, 2, 5, 8, 7, 1, 5, 6]`.

I tried this code and it works:

```
data = np.array([0, 4, 4, 2, 5, 8, 5, 8, 7, 1, 5, 6, 1, 5, 6])
for k in range(1, 3):
    kth_difference = data[k:] - data[:-k]
    ids = np.where(kth_difference)
    data = data[ids]
```

But if I change input list to something like `data = [0, 4, 4, 2, 5, 8, 5, 8, 7, 1, 5, 6, 1, 5]` (broke the last set), the new output list is `[0, 4, 2, 5, 8, 7, 1, 5]`, which lost `6` at the end.

What a solution for this task? How to make this solution workable for any `k`?

Comment: [1, 5, 1, 5] should probably be [5, 8, 5, 8]?

Comment: Yes, sorry, my mistake)

Comment: What happens to `2, 2, 2, 2`? Is it `2, 2` or `2`? Or guaranteed never to happen?

Comment: This should be a ```2```. If you are interested, this is a simplified subtask, the goal is to remove duplicate words that arise on image captioning, when captions are generated by a neural network, where the list items are the indexes of words in the dictionary

Comment: Also what hapens with `2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1` ? `2, 2, 1` or `2, 1` or `2, 1, 2, 1` ?

Comment: As I said, we should look at the list as a tokenized sentence with indexes of words from the dictionary. This means, that in all the cases you proposed, the answer [2, 1] should be correct. But my (wrong) code was returning empty list

Comment: If you describe an image you don't need duplicated information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You added a numpy tag, so let's use that to our advantage. Start with an array:

```
data = np.array([0, 4, 4, 2, 5, 8, 5, 8, 7, 1, 5, 6, 1, 5, 6])
```

It's easy to make a mask of elements up to length `n` that follow each other:

```
mask_1 = data[1:] == data[:-1]
mask_2 = data[2:] == data[:-2]
mask_3 = data[3:] == data[:-3]
```

The first mask has ones at each location where the next element is the same. The second mask will have a one wherever an element is the same as something two elements ahead, so you need to find runs of 2 elements at a time. The same applies to the third mask. Filtering of the mask needs to take into account that you want to include the possibility of partial matches at the end. You can effectively extend the mask with `k-1` elements to accomplish this:

```
delta = np.diff(np.r_[False, mask_3, np.ones(2, dtype=bool), False].view(np.int8))
edges = np.flatnonzero(delta).reshape(-1, 2)
lengths = edges[:, 1] - edges[:, 0]
delta[edges[lengths < 3, :]] = 0
mask = delta[-k:].cumsum(dtype=np.int8).view(bool)
```

In this arrangement, `mask` masks the duplicated three elements that constitute a duplicated group. It may contain fewer than three elements if the replicated portion is truncated. That ensures that you get to keep all the elements of partial duplicates.

For this exercise, I will assume that you don't have strange overlaps between different levels. I.e., each part of the array that belongs to a repeated segment belongs to exactly one possible repeated segment. Otherwise, the mask processing becomes much more complex.

Here is a function to wrap all this together:

```
def clean_mask(mask, k):
    delta = np.diff(np.r_[False, mask, np.ones(k - 1, bool), False].view(np.int8))
    edges = np.flatnonzero(delta).reshape(-1, 2)
    lengths = edges[:, 1] - edges[:, 0]
    delta[edges[lengths < k, :]] = 0
    return delta[:-k].cumsum(dtype=np.int8).view(bool)

def dedup(data, kmax):
    data = np.asarray(data)
    kmax = min(kmax, data.size // 2)

    remove = np.zeros(data.shape, dtype=np.bool)
    for k in range(kmax, 0, -1):
        remove[k:] |= clean_mask(data[k:] == data[:-k], k)
    return data[~remove]
```

Outputs for the two test cases you show in the question:

```
>>> dedup([0, 4, 4, 2, 5, 8, 5, 8, 7, 1, 5, 6, 1, 5, 6], 3)
array([0, 4, 2, 5, 8, 7, 1, 5, 6])

>>> dedup([0, 4, 4, 2, 5, 8, 5, 8, 7, 1, 5, 6, 1, 5], 3)
array([0, 4, 2, 5, 8, 7, 1, 5, 6])
```

**Timing**

A quick benchmark shows that the numpy solution is also much faster than pure python:

```
for n in range(2, 7):
    x = np.random.randint(0, 10, 10**n)
    y = list(x)
    %timeit dedup(x, 3)
    %timeit remdup(y)
```

Results:

```
# 100 elements
 dedup: 332 µs ± 5.01 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
remdup: 36.9 ms ± 152 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# 1000 elements
 dedup: 412 µs ± 5.88 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
remdup: > 1 minute
```

**Caveats**

This solution makes no attempt to cover corner cases. For example: `data = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]` or similar, where multiple levels of `k` can overlap.

Comment: Thanks, your solution is really interesting!

Comment: @Plaeryin_Bol Thanks. It's also much faster. I'm adding some timings

Answer (score 1):

Here is an attempt, which is also my very first time using `break` and `for/else`:

```py
def remdup(l):
  while True:
    for (i,j) in ((i,j) for i in range(0,len(l)) for j in range(i+1, len(l)+1)):
      if l[i:j] == l[j:j+(j-i)]:
        l = l[:j] + l[j+j-i:]
        break  # restart
    else:  # if no duplicate was found
      break  # halt
  return l

print(remdup([0, 4, 4, 2, 5, 8, 5, 8, 7, 1, 5, 6, 1, 5, 6]))
# [0, 4, 2, 5, 8, 7, 1, 5, 6]
```

How this works:

- iterate on all substrings `l[i:j]`:

  - if `l[i:j]` is duplicate with the next substring of same length, `l[j,j+j-i]`:

    - remove `l[j,j+j-i]`
    - break the iteration and restart it because the list has changed
  - if no duplicate was found, return the list

I recommend avoiding using `break` and `for/else`. They're ugly and make deceptive code.

Comment: Thanks for your help!